# Hbase not condition in compound filter

Tags: java, hbase

I want to build compound filter.
I can do something like this

```
(filter1 and filter2) or filter3
```

Now I want to build the same filter, but with negative function

```
(**NOT** (filter1 and filter2)) or filter3
```

And I want to do it with java client api (**`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client`**)

Comment: Alex : Anything found?, Out of ext. experience with hbase for this kind of queries you have to go for Solr/otherways rather pure hbase filters. If you are applying these on column values it may be very flow and may table to full table scans.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [FilterList](http://javadox.com/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/1.1.2/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html) to do this kind of condition.

[FilterList 
Implementation of Filter that represents an ordered List of Filters which will be evaluated with a specified boolean operator FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL (AND) or FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE (OR).](http://javadox.com/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/1.1.2/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html)

AFAIK negation as shown above is not possible directly with FilterList.  I'd suggest to use  SOLR(May be Elastic search also) to do this. If you are using Cloudera Solr(Cloudera Search) is useful for this.